# When updating Chart.js chart the data is updated but canvas is emptied

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I'm creating multiple charts in my html page with Chart.js and after window has loaded charts are updated dynamically in every second with new data values. I'm handling the updating with Chart.js update() function. All created charts are stored in global array where those are then fetched to be updated.

Updating works as it should when I first time open my html page and graphs are updated every second(showing live measured data), but when I move to another subpage in my webapp and then return back to the page where graphs should be, all canvases are empty(data in charts is updating as it should but canvases stays blank).

When I'm moving to subpage I'm only updating part of the html content including area where those canvases are and when I'm returning to frontpage I load that same area with same html content than first time when I open my webpage.

So currently what I'm doing is that when I return to page where charts should be rendered I fetch old charts from global chart-array(created when webpage is first time opened), replacing old datasets with new ones and then calling the Chart.js update() function. I know that the datasets are updated every second like they did when I open webpage first time as I wanted(I check this with console) but canvases are emptied so those updated charts are not shown anywhere anymore.

This is my canvas when updating works properly:

```
<canvas id="etaisyyskuvaaja" height="200" width="350" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></canvas>
```

And this is how it looks like when trying to update after returning from subpage:

```
<canvas id="etaisyyskuvaaja"></canvas>
```

So that's what I mean with "emptied".

I thought that when I'm updating old chart that has once been created in specific canvas it should be automatically rendered to that same canvas when data is updated (actually this does work this way when html content stays the same when I first time open webpage). 
However now it seems that re-rendering doesn't work anymore when I have changed html content (moved to subpage) and then loaded those canvases again (returning to frontpage and start cyclic updating again).

Can someone tell why my charts are updated with new data as they should but canvases are emptied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I thought that maybe I need to fetch canvas elements again and pass them somehow to the update-function if the chart-instance somehow does have miss the original canvas after removing html content and then loaded it back or something.

However I wasn't able to figure out the solution where I update those canvases so I managed to fix the problem like this:

When returning to front page I first loop through the array of charts and remove all charts that are suppose to be in my front page(create last time when front page has been loaded). Then I create those charts again after the html content have been loaded and save those in my array of charts. Now when I start cyclic updating of those newly created charts the updating works again like a charm!

Comment: Hello! I hope it's not too late to ask, something similar happens to me with chartjs, in my case when I load the design for the first time it shows as I have it configured but once I update the design it moves. That is, if I had a label at the top when I update, the bottom appears. I am using chartjs-node-canvas, can you help me?